# Maximal subgroup satisfying condition

Tags: group-theory

I have a problem that I don't have any idea.

show that if $M$ is Maximal subgroup of group $G$ then $Z(G)$$\leq$$M$ or $G'$$\leq$$M$.

Comment: $Z(G) \not\le M \Rightarrow G=MZ(G) \Rightarrow G'=M'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Z=Z(G)$ is not contained in $M$. Since $Z$ is normal, $ZM$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing properly $M$, i.e. $ZM=G$.

Now, notice that $G'$ is generated by elements of the form
$$[mz, nw] \ \ \ \ \mbox{ with } m,n \in M , z,w \in Z$$
but elements of $Z$ commute with any other element of $G$, so
$$[mz, nw] = [m,n] \in M$$
Hence generators of $G'$ belong to $M$. This implies that $G' \le M$.